# How configure a GPG on my ArchLinux and sign it on my GitHub if I am getting [GNUPG:] PINENTRY_LAUNCHED 16376 curses 1.2.1 - - :0.0 - 1000/1000 0?

Tags: linux, git, github

I've created my GPG key based on the GitHub Documentation, which means that I made:

```bash
gpg --full-generate-key

gpg --list-secret-keys --keyid-format=long

$ gpg --list-secret-keys --keyid-format=long
/Users/hubot/.gnupg/secring.gpg
------------------------------------
sec   4096R/3AA5C34371567BD2 2016-03-10 [expires: 2017-03-10]
uid                          Hubot <hubot@example.com>
ssb   4096R/4BB6D45482678BE3 2016-03-10

gpg --armor --export 3AA5C34371567BD2
```

After that, I tried to add it on my .gitconfig such as

```bash
[commit]
    gpgsign = true
[gpg]
    program = /usr/bin/gpg2
```

I am setting gpg2 because when I run `gpg --version` I get:

```bash
[b@the-b-arch ~]$ gpg --version
gpg (GnuPG) 2.2.41
libgcrypt 1.10.2-unknown
Copyright (C) 2022 g10 Code GmbH
License GNU GPL-3.0-or-later <https://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

Home: /home/b/.gnupg
Supported algorithms:
Pubkey: RSA, ELG, DSA, ECDH, ECDSA, EDDSA
Cipher: IDEA, 3DES, CAST5, BLOWFISH, AES, AES192, AES256, TWOFISH,
        CAMELLIA128, CAMELLIA192, CAMELLIA256
Hash: SHA1, RIPEMD160, SHA256, SHA384, SHA512, SHA224
Compression: Uncompressed, ZIP, ZLIB, BZIP2
```

I also addeed to my .bashzrc the lines

```bash
GPG_TTY=$(tty)
export GPG_TTY
```

However, I am still getting it when I try to sign a commit:

```bash
> git -c user.useConfigOnly=true commit --quiet --allow-empty-message --file -
error: gpg failed to sign the data:
[GNUPG:] KEY_CONSIDERED 3B9CAC1EE7A5F97A1B10123D6F4F7B6D29518083 2
[GNUPG:] BEGIN_SIGNING H8
[GNUPG:] PINENTRY_LAUNCHED 12345 custompinentry 1.0.0 - - :0.0 - 1000/1000 0
gpg: signing failed: Inappropriate ioctl for device
[GNUPG:] FAILURE sign 11223344
gpg: signing failed: Inappropriate ioctl for device

fatal: failed to write commit object
```

I need to sign all my future commmits.

Answer (score 1):

Try first, if you have a GUI available, to use pinentry-gnome3, and adjust your `~/.gnupg/gpg-agent.conf`

```
sudo pacman -S pinentry-gnome3
```

[This thread](https://dev.gnupg.org/T4677) mentions:

> Digging more, it looks like the underlying issue is related to using `pinentry-tty` (my case) or `pinentry-curses` when passing the OpenPGP input via standard input. This causes pinentry to give up before prompting.
> For `pinentry-tty` it fails with "`ERR 83886340 Invalid IPC response`" and `pinentty-curses` fails with "`ERR 83918950 Inappropriate ioctl for device`".
>
> In other words, this command only works when using a GUI-style pinentry:
>
> ```
> $ gpg --decrypt <message.gpg
> ```
>
> But this works either way since it doesn't tie up standard input:
>
> ```
> $ gpg --decrypt message.gpg
> ```
>
> I'd expect `pinentry-tty/-curses` to work in the first case since it would use `/dev/tty` directly, not rely on standard input/output as the tty.

---

If using a GUI is not possible, you need a different approach which does not use stdin.

When Git makes a GPG signing request, it does not pass data to GPG via a file, but uses standard input (stdin) to do so. That is largely because it is more efficient and secure - writing potentially sensitive data to disk even temporarily can be risky.

However, you can have a workaround by making use of a wrapper script for the `gpg` command that Git uses for signing. That script will make sure the data is written to a temporary file and then passed to `gpg`, so that it is not using stdin.

For testing, create a file somewhere in your `PATH` (like `/usr/local/bin/`), named `gpgwrap` for instance. Make sure this directory is added to your `PATH` environment variable.

```bash
#!/bin/bash
# gpgwrap

# Generate a temporary file
TEMPFILE=$(mktemp)

# Save the input to the temporary file
cat > "$TEMPFILE"

# Call gpg with the temporary file as an argument
/usr/bin/gpg "$@" "$TEMPFILE"

# Clean up
rm "$TEMPFILE"
```

It reads from stdin, saves it to a temporary file, and then calls `gpg` with the filename as an argument.

Run `chmod +x /usr/local/bin/gpgwrap` to make the script executable.

And update your Git configuration to use the `gpgwrap` script for signing:

```bash
git config --global gpg.program gpgwrap
```

That script should work for most cases, but please note that it is not a universal solution - it does not account for scenarios where `gpg` might be called with an already existing file as an argument: use it to test if your issue is linked to stdin.